# How do I estimate the number of neutron stars and black holes relative to the number of stars in the main sequence and white dwarfs?

Tags: black-hole, stellar-astrophysics, white-dwarf

Recently, I had a homework question that gave me the mass of a main-sequence star, that is, M_tp = 0.9 M_solar, and the population formed at the same time. I am supposed to use the stellar birth function to help determine the answer. However, I still have no idea how to approach this. Can someone explain how someone would approach this question?

Comment: What is M_tp? Just some stellar mass from one part of the homework?

Comment: So, there is a specific mass where the main-sequence star gets off the main-sequence to turn into a giant. By the terms of this question, this is assuming that the main-sequence star gets off of the main-sequence with a solar mass M = 0.9

Comment: Is the question to estimate the number of black holes, etc in the galaxy or within that cluster? If the latter: what's the mass and age?

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/4725/statistically-what-would-the-average-distance-of-the-closest-black-hole-be https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/how-far-away-is-the-nearest-compact-star-remnant-likely-to-be?noredirect=1&lq=1